# Get and set the field value by passing name

Tags: c#, reflection, field

I have a field in a class with a random name like:

```
class Foo {
    public string a2de = "e2"
}
```

I have the name of this field in another variable like:

```
string vari = "a2de"
```

Can I get or set the value of field `a2de` by using the value of `vari`?

like:

```
getvar(vari)
```

or

```
setvar(vari) = "e3"
```

Comment: try reflection to acheive this.

Comment: I get a feeling that you are confusing terminology a bit (for instance; what is *a variable in another variable*?) Please provide a fuller code example showing what you try to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use reflection.

To get the value of a property on `targetObject`:

```
var value = targetObject.GetType().GetProperty(vari).GetValue(targetObject, null);
```

To get the value of a field it's similar:

```
var value = targetObject.GetType().GetField(vari).GetValue(targetObject, null);
```

If the property/field is not public or it has been inherited from a base class, you will need to provide explicit `BindingFlags` to `GetProperty` or `GetField`.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* potentially do it with *reflection* (e.g. `Type.GetField` etc) - but that should generally be a last resort.

Have you considered using a `Dictionary<string, string>` and using the "variable name" as the key instead?

Comment: If the post was talking about __local__ variables rather than type fields then this will not work.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: True. These days I think we'd have insisted on more details in the question to start with.

Comment: No problem. I only ended here because another user referred to your answer here as authoritative proof that local variables can be modified via reflection. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41867476/158285

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use Reflection to access the variable by name. Like this:

```
class Foo
{
    int namedField = 1;
    string vari = "namedField"

    void AccessField()
    {
        int val = (int) GetType().InvokeMember(vari,
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        BindingFlags.GetField, null, this, null);
        // now you should have 1 in val.
    }
}
```