# Reference variable name dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
public struct ChannelSettings
{
    public double slider20Hz;
    public double slider25Hz;
    public double slider31_5Hz;
    public double slider40Hz;
}
```

and I am looping through my user interface objects when a slider value is changed like this:

```
foreach (Slider slider in grdEqSliders.Children)
{
     // slidername = slider.Name;
     switch(currentChannel)
     {
         case 1:
            // Assign to channel.slidername
            break;
         case 2:
            // Assign to channel.slidername
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
}
```

My question is, is there a way for me to get the sliders name then turn it in to something I can reference directly in my structure?
For example I would like to turn the `slider.Name = "slider_20Hz"` in to the variable `slider20Hz` that I use in my struct.

Comment: Well, you can switch on a string; just have the cases be each of those four strings, rather than 1, 2, 3, 4.  You could use reflection, but in a case this simple the `switch` is probably easier.

Comment: I will have multiple structs though and need to make sure the value is getting put in to the correct one.

Comment: Accessing the appropriate variable (once you have its name) is addressed by [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218625/get-and-set-the-variable-value-by-passing-name) - you can do so using reflection.   A (possibly) better solution, if it works for your codebase, would be store the doubles in a dictionary - the current var "name" becomes the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do that leaving the `struct` defined as it is now is to use reflection - pretty messy though.

An alternative - changing the definition - is to store the values in a dictionary:

```
public class ChannelSettings {
  Dictionary<string, double> _values = new Dictionary<string, double>();

   public double slider20Hz {
     get {
       return GetByName("slider20Hz");
     }
     set {
       _values["slider20Hz"] = value;
     }
   }

   . . . 

   public void SetByName(string name, double value) {
     _values[name] = value;
   }

   public double GetByName(string name) {
     double v;
     if (_values.TryGetValue("slider20Hz", out v)) {
       return v;
     }
     return 0.0; // Default value
   }

}
```

and then to set a value given its name you can write:

```
channel.SetByName(slider.Name, . . . )
```

and to get a value:

```
channel.GetByName(slider.Name)
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about doing it that way, this should work perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: `There is no way to do that leaving the struct defined as it is now.`  Sure there is; you can do exactly what you've done using reflection if you *really want to*, although you probably wouldn't want to.

Comment: How would I call this to get the information back out by passing in the string name?

Comment: @IanOswald: see updated answer (if I understood correctly your question)

Answer (score 1):

The Slider control, as all FrameworkElements, has a Tag property for these types of situations where you need a property for your own use.

```
<Slider Tag="slider_20Hz"/>

foreach (Slider slider in grdEqSliders.Children)
{
     slidername = slider.Tag as string;
     ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting that, but then need to reference the variable in the struct with the similar name.