# combine two strings and convert it to integer variable

Tags: c#

I want to take two strings and their combination will give a name of integer variable for example:

```
int Value1 = 0;
int Value2 = 0;
.
.
.
int Value30 = 0;
int index = 0;
string startOfVar = "Value";
```

and now i want to do something like this:

```
(startOfVar & index) = 50;
```

so, if index = 1 then Value1 will be change to 50.
if index = 25 then Value25 will be change to 50.
Obviously, i don't want to do it with array...

I hope the question is clear...

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Where are those variables stored? Are those properties or fields of a class? If so you may use reflection to change the values based on their names.

Comment: Why arrays are not a valid solution for your problem? Maybe you should edit your question and explain a little bit the case you will be using this

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218625/get-and-set-the-variable-value-by-passing-name

Comment: because I got a very unorganized code, and to do it properly (with array, classes etc.) I need to rewrite the whole code...

Comment: Then,reflection is your only way I think

Comment: Answer @HimBromBeere 's question, and we might have a chance to help you.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to use reflection, don't.  It doesn't seem to be what you need.  Rewriting your code shouldn't be too hard, since it's basically searching any uses of ValueX and replacing them with Value[X].

Comment: How are your int variables created in the first place? Are they hard coded?

Comment: If you have that bad code: rewrite it. Don't make it worse with reflection.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  and Jestin In the code there are over 15 packages of ValueX (with different name for each package) so it might be take me a while to rewrite. anyway, it is another cool stuff to know...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you're looking for a `Dictionary<String, int>` where each `String` key (`"Value1"`..`"Value30"`) represents some `int` value:

```
Dictionary<String, int> data = Enumerable
  .Range(1, 30)
  .ToDictionary(x => String.Format("Value{0}", x),
                x => 0);

...

  int index = 1;
  string startOfVar = "Value";

  data[startOfVar + index.ToString()] = 50;

  Console.Write(data["Value1"]);
```

Comment: Nice solution,didn't think of that. Upvoted