# How to combine two strings into the name of another string and call that string?

Tags: c#, string, class

is there any way to simplify this code into a few lines, I have a class with string seq(number) has {get;set} functions. I am getting lucio and textValue from another class.

```
public static void setCategorySeq(string lucio, string textValue)
    {
        if (lucio == "0") { seq0 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "1") { seq1 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "2") { seq2 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "3") { seq3 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "4") { seq4 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "5") { seq5 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "6") { seq6 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "7") { seq7 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "8") { seq8 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "9") { seq9 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "10") { seq10 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "11") { seq11 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "12") { seq12 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "13") { seq13 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "14") { seq14 = textValue; }
        else if (lucio == "15") { seq15 = textValue; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure if I understand your question. But I think what you are looking for is that you can call a key (e.g. lucio) and you want to set its respective value (e.g. seq). Am I right?

Comment: you should use Switch statement for that kind of work.

Comment: As @UmairAnwaar mentions, switch would be the best for this situation, although personally, I like shortening number of lines, so I'd look into Reflection (not sure if it will be better) to "set" a variable's value based on its name as string. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5218649/6741868

Comment: @KeyurPATEL You can set a property by reflection but you can't set a local variable by reflection. A dictionary is the best solution probably for what the user is trying to do.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Yes, while looking around I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5218652/6741868. If Jon Skeet says so, there is no doubt.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I'm hesitant to argue with Jon Skeet but in this case his answer is wrong in the context of the question asked. You cannot get to local variables via reflection as the name information is erased during compilation. You would need the debug information that is stored in the PDB file and then find a way to use it like the debugger does. Not impossible but lots of hoops to jump through. ``Type.GetField`` will not do this for you.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I asked Jon Skeet about this and he confirmed that his answer was wrong given that the original question was about local variables and not fields. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5218652/158285

Comment: I guess I was wrong, I remember trying something similar long ago, I was under the impression I had accessed local variables, but maybe they were just class fields.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: To be clear, *this* question is about local variables. The question I *answered* is simply unclear about what kind of variable it's talking about. (The fact that it has an accepted answer - not mine - that uses reflection suggests the OP there really was interested in fields.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess "wrong" is too strong a word. I could edit the post on the referenced question to clarify it is about fields rather than local variables.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've gone ahead and fixed it. It now reflects the answers and can't be confused with the question on this page.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: Great - that will definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this could help you reducing the LOC.

```
    public static void setCategorySeq(string lucio, string textValue)
    {
        string[] seq = new string[16];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            if (lucio == i.ToString())
                seq[i] = textValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will suit you:

`static Dictionary<string, string> seq = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public static void setCategorySeq(string lucio, string textValue)
        {
            seq[lucio] = textValue;
        }
        public static string setCategorySeq(string lucio)
        {
            if (seq.ContainsKey(lucio))
                return seq[lucio];
            return null;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dictionary

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

then to set an entry in the dictionary

```
lookup[lucio] = textValue;
```

and to access it

```
Console.WriteLine(lookup[lucio])
```

if you really want to verify that the string is a value between 0 an 15 then parse it first and validate it and use a dictionary with integer as a key

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int,string>();

// Using C# 7 notation
if(int.TryParse(lucio, var out lucioInt) && lucionInt > 0 && lucioInt < 16){
    lookup[lucioInt] = textValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help

```
public static void setCategorySeq(string lucio, string textValue)
{
var seq = new string[15];
int noOfsequence=15;
for(int i=0;i<noOfsequence;i++)
    {
        if(lucio==i.ToString())
        {
         seq[i] = textValue;
         break;
        }

    }



 }
```