# How to set different values to variables that differ in 1 character i loop? (C#)

Tags: c#

I have multiple variables in my WinForms, like name1, name2, name3...
And the number of these variables changes depending on the given information on the text, I just make unnecessary labels not visible. I want to know, if it possible to do such like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    ("name"+i.toString()).toVar().Text = text;
}
```

Or I need to do it manually?

Comment: you have to use an array for something like that.

Comment: nope, thought about it, but it won't help at all

Comment: What do you mean it won't help?

Comment: This is the sort of thing arrays were *made* for.  I'm curious that you considered and rejected them without explaining why.

Comment: Is `("name"+i.toString()).toVar().Text` supposed to be a Label control reference?

Comment: I need to convert string to a name of  a variable somehow, because I have like from 1 to , depending on given information in the text file, and if I will do it with switch, the code will be very unpleasant and arrays won't help me with that

Comment: you have an x-y problem here. consider a dictionary.

Comment: @LarsTech, yes, I meant it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218625/get-and-set-the-field-value-by-passing-name

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you mind to update your question?

Answer (score -1):

WinForms itself has a lookup-by-name capability, the `Controls` collection.  Your code can be written as:

```
Controls["name"+i.toString()].Text = text;
```

It's like a dictionary, but it's automatically configured for all controls the designer adds to the form, so you don't have to add items by hand the way you would for an array or your own dictionary.